# Labeled loop,continue keyord does not work

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Details {
    int num;
    String NAMES[][];
    double MARKS[][];
    double TOTAL[];
    String GRADES[];

    void getData() {
        Scanner ob = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.print("Enter the number of students : ");
        num = ob.nextInt();
        NAMES = new String[num][2];
        MARKS = new double[num][4];
        for (int x = 0; x
            System.out.print("First Name : ");
            NAMES[x][0] = ob.next();
            System.out.print("Last Name : ");
            NAMES[x][1] = ob.next();
            loop1: 
            for (int p = 1; p <= 1; p++)
            {
                System.out.print("\tFirst Test Marks : ");
                MARKS[x][0] = ob.nextDouble();
                if ((MARKS[x][0] < 0) || (MARKS[x][0] > 15))
                {
                    System.out.println("Marks should be within 0 to 15");
                    continue loop1;
                }
            }
            loop2: 
            for (int p = 1; p <= 1; p++)
            {
                System.out.print("\tMid Term Marks : ");
                MARKS[x][1] = ob.nextDouble();
                if (MARKS[x][1] < 0 || MARKS[x][1] > 20)
                {
                    System.out.println("Marks should be within 0 to 20");
                    continue loop2;
                }
            }
            loop3: 
            for (int p = 1; p <= 1; p++)
            {
                System.out.print("\tLab Test Marks : ");
                MARKS[x][2] = ob.nextDouble();
                if (MARKS[x][2] < 0 || MARKS[x][2] > 15)
                {
                    System.out.println("Marks should be within 0 to 15");
                    continue loop3;
                }
            }
            loop4: 
            for (int p = 1; p <= 1; p++)
            {
                System.out.print("\tFinal Marks : ");
                MARKS[x][3] = ob.nextDouble();
                if (MARKS[x][3] < 0 || MARKS[x][3] > 50)
                {
                    System.out.println("Marks should be within 0 to 20");
                    continue loop4;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public void total() {
        TOTAL = new double[num];
        for (int x = 0; x
            TOTAL[x] = MARKS[x][0] + MARKS[x][1] + MARKS[x][2] + MARKS[x][3];
        }
    }
    public void grades() {
        GRADES = new String[num];
        for (int x = 0; x
            if (TOTAL[x] >= 80) {
                GRADES[x] = "A";
            } else if (TOTAL[x] >= 70) {
                GRADES[x] = "B";
            } else if (TOTAL[x] >= 60) {
                GRADES[x] = "C";
            } else if (TOTAL[x] >= 50) {
                GRADES[x] = "D";
            } else {
                GRADES[x] = "F";
            }
        }
    }
    void print() {
        System.out.println("\t\t\tRESULT SHEET\n\n\tFirst Name\tLast Name\tGrade");
        for (int x = 0; x
            System.out.println("\t" + NAMES[x][0] + "\t\t" + NAMES[x][1] + "\t\t" + GRADES[x]);
        }
    }
}
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Details data = new Details();
        data.getData();
        data.total();
        data.grades();
        data.print();
    }
}
```

the problem with continue keyword, it doesn't work weather we give wrong input

Comment: Please format your post appropriately - not just indenting the code (until it's in a code font) but also removing the blank lines. Additionally, give more details - "it doesn't work" is never enough information. I'd also strongly advise you to start following Java naming conventions.

Comment: And what is this `for (int x = 0; x` supposed to do? Did you missed it's half part?

Comment: Yep,, this is a program that give input and calculate the grade, for example if i give a wrong input "100" for first mark, i want that the program will continue with loop (Because i put labeled loop)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you've understood the meaning of the `continue` keyword. The `continue`s you've used won't do anything at their current position. Take for instance this segment:

```
loop1: 
for (int p = 1; p <= 1; p++)
{
    System.out.print("\tFirst Test Marks : ");
    MARKS[x][0] = ob.nextDouble();
    if ((MARKS[x][0] < 0) || (MARKS[x][0] > 15))
    {
        System.out.println("Marks should be within 0 to 15");
        continue loop1;
    }
}
```

When the if-condition succeeds, it prints something and then it **continues with the next iteration of loop1**. It would've continued with the next iteration anyways, since the `continue` keyword is at the end of the looped segment. However, since all your for-loops run only once, there **is no next iteration** and the loop is stopped.

Perhaps a better solution is to use a while-loop like this:

```
while(true) {
    System.out.print("\tFirst Test Marks : ");
    MARKS[x][0] = ob.nextDouble();
    if ((MARKS[x][0] < 0) || (MARKS[x][0] > 15)) {
        System.out.println("Marks should be within 0 to 15");
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your loops length of 1: `loop1: for (int p = 1; p <= 1; p++)` Once it is re-entered, `p<=1` is evaluted to false and the loop is exited. I would suggest something like this:

```
        boolean firstConditionSatisfied = false;
        while (!firstConditionSatisfied) {
            System.out.print("\tFirst Test Marks : ");
            MARKS[x][0] = ob.nextDouble();
            if ((MARKS[x][0] < 0) || (MARKS[x][0] > 15)) {
                System.out.println("Marks should be within 0 to 15");
            } else {
                firstConditionSatisfied = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ohh... Really thank you, its working. But If I use BufferReader for scanner, it will be a error message

unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown


 num=Integer.parseInt(ob1.readLine());

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't understand what `continue` does, it's used to skip the remaining part of a loop and start again. Labelling loops is only necessary if you've got nested loops and want to `continue` (or `break` out of) an outer loop.

(Offtopic: I would suggest to create a new class like `Student` with first name, last name and marks so the code gets easier to read.)

Answer (score 0):

Java rule #1: if you use labels and jumps, the structure of your code is wrong. No exceptions.

Therefore to solve this issue, you should change the question to: "How to properly modify this code to remove the jumps?"